# OTP sending to email using Azure MFA SDK for java

Tags: java, azure

Hi im using Azure MFA SDK for java in my java applucation. I have sent OTP to my mobile phone successfully using this sdk. May i know how i can sent OTP to my email?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to do the Azure MFA verification via email. So I dived into Azure AD portal to find the email option, but there is no email verification option, as below.

Fig 1. Click and move to MFA on Azure AD Portal
[image]

Fig 2. There is no email option in the service settings
[image]

So it seems to not possible to do that as you wish in the cloud.

However, for on-premises, the offical document [Getting started with the Azure Multi-Factor Authentication Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-server#send-users-an-email) shown that allow MFA Server to communicate with users and how to configure MFA Server to send an email to inform them that they have been enrolled for two-step verification.

Meanwhile, there is a [blog](https://4sysops.com/archives/azure-multi-factor-authentication-part-5-settings/#email) shown the configuration interface for MFA via email.

Hope it helps.